Django route cannot be accessed during fetch POST method but can be accessed during manual GET method
When I attempt to delete a faction from my application using the route saga/delete/2 after clicking the deleteSubmit button, the program returns the following error:
"POST /saga/delete/2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3048
Not Found: /saga/delete/2/
My application uses the following relevant url patterns
#project/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path("saga/", include("saga.urls")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

#saga/urls.py
app_name = "saga"

urlpatterns = [
    #ex: /saga/
    path("", views.index, name = "index"),
    #ex: /saga/results/1
    path("results/<int:factionId>",views.results, name = 'results'),
    #ex: /saga/edit/
    path("create/", views.create, name = 'create'),
    #ex: /saga/edit/1
    path("edit/<int:factionId>", views.edit, name = 'edit'),  
    #ex: /saga/delete/1
    path("delete/<int:factionId>", views.delete, name = 'delete')
    #ex: /saga/edit/push/?
]

This JavaScript handles the form submission
factionForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        //prevent the default form submission
        event.preventDefault(); 
        //If the Save Changes button is clicked
        if (event.submitter === saveSubmit){
            console.log("Save Changes Pressed");
            // Code to handle form submission and save changes to the database
        }

        //Otherwise if the Delete changes button is clicked
        else if(event.submitter === deleteSubmit){
            console.log("Delete Faction Pressed");
            //Attempt to send data to server
            fetch(`/saga/delete/${factionId.value}/`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRFToken': getCSRF(),
                },
            })
            //Get response from server
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    console.log('Faction deleted successfully');
                } else {
                    //If a problem occurred display the response
                    console.error('Error deleting faction',response);
                }
            })
            //If There is an error output it
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        }

        //Otherwise if neither approved button submitted the form something went wrong
        else {
            console.log(event.submitter, "somehow submitted the form, check and correct the code near that element");
        }
    })

The code I am using for the getCSRF() function is here:
function getCSRF() {
    const cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        const [name, value] = cookies[i].split('=');
        if (name === "csrfToken") {
            return decodeURIComponent(value);
        }
    }
  return null;
}

Here is the relevant view function as well
def delete(request,factionId):
    #Get Faction To Delete
    faction = Faction.objects.filter(id = factionId)
    #If Faction Exists and Data has been posted from a form
    if faction.count() > 0 and request.method == 'POST':
        #Delete the faction
        faction.delete()
        #Return to create page on success (Will change to success message later)
        return redirect(reverse("saga:create"))
    
    #Return to home page on failure (happens currently during a Get request
    return redirect(reverse("saga:index"))    

My form has been defined like so:
<form id = "factionForm" method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
<!-- Lots of Code -->
</form>

What am I missing and how do I change my code so that my POST is accepted?
I have attempted to remove the csrf_token and use the @csrf_exempt decorator with no success.
I have attempted to use different functions to obtain the csrf_token but as far as I can tell my current one is obtaining the token.
I have checked my settings.py file to check that 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' is present, and it is.
I have attempted to change the url patterns without any success.

This is not a problem of CSRF but it seems a problem with the URLs being used. Please add the complete URL pattern lines

I have added the complete URL pattern lines.

Probably this is the problem:
fetch(`/saga/delete/${factionId.value}/.....

notice the slash at the end. But in your urls.py:
path("delete/<int:factionId>", views.delete, name = 'delete')

you don't have a trailing slash. I think that might be the problem that you should have a trailing slash. Try removing or adding a trailing slash in both the above provided lines of code and see if it works.
